# Potential leak of memory in linked list

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Element{
    int key;
    Element *prev, *next;
};

Element* find(Element* head, int key){
    while(head!=nullptr && head->key!=key)
        head = head->next;
    return head;
}

void insert_after(Element* elem, Element* new_el, Element *& tail){

    if(elem == nullptr){
        cout<<"Error: can't insert"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    new_el->prev = elem;
    new_el->next = elem->next;
    elem->next = new_el;
    if(new_el->next != nullptr)
        new_el->next->prev = new_el;
    else
        tail= new_el;
}

void insert_in_head(Element *& head, Element* new_el, Element *& tail){
    new_el->next = head;
    new_el->prev = nullptr;
    if(head!=nullptr)
        head->prev = new_el;
    else
        tail= new_el;
    head = new_el;
}

void deleteNode(Element *& head, Element* elem, Element *& tail){
    if(elem==nullptr){
        cout<<"Error: can't delete"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if(elem->prev==nullptr && elem->next==nullptr){
        head=nullptr;
        tail=nullptr;
    }else{
        if(elem->prev!=nullptr)
            elem->prev->next=elem->next;
        else{
            head=elem->next;
            head->prev=nullptr;
        }
        if(elem->next!=nullptr)
            elem->next->prev=elem->prev;
        else{
            tail=elem->prev;
            tail->next=nullptr;
        }
    }
    delete elem;
}


int main()
{
    Element* head=nullptr;
    Element* tail=nullptr;


    int choice, input, key_after;
    bool running = true;

    while(running){      // <--Warning here 
        cin>>choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        {
            cin>>input;
            Element* new_el = new Element;
            new_el->key=input;
            insert_in_head(head, new_el, tail);
           break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            cin>>key_after>>input;
            Element* new_el = new Element;
            new_el->key=input;
            insert_after(find(head, key_after), new_el, tail);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            cin>>input;
            deleteNode(head, find(head, input), tail);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            cin>>input;
            Element* new_el = new Element;
            new_el->key=input;
            insert_after(tail, new_el, tail);
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The warning i get in Qt Creator is: Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'new_el'. I understnad that I'm creating new_el with new, but I don't know where/when to delete it. I delete the pointer later with deleteNode function. If I delete case 2 or case 4 the warning goes away, but that is I think this is probably a coincidence.

Comment: If you were actually writing C++, you'd delete nodes in your destructor. But this, being a C-style linked list, does make it more interesting.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt Creator so I don't know if this is what it's flagging, but you have logic that returns from e.g. `insert_after` if the `elem` argument equals `nullptr`. You should free the `new_el` argument in those cases.

Comment: Please when giving us that much code to read, make sure it's formatted to be fully readable.

Comment: Also, put a big fat comment in showing us which line has the warning.

Comment: After adding a delete new_el inside first if statement in insert_after function the warning went away.